# Is it possible to render in RGB888 with OpenGL?

Tags: android, opengl-es

I have played for a while with OpenGL on Android on various devices. And unless I'm wrong, the default rendering is always performed with the RGB565 pixel format.

I would however like to render more accurate colors using RGB888.

The [GLSurfaceView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/GLSurfaceView.html) documentation mentions two methods which relate to pixel formats:

- the [setFormat()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceHolder.html#setFormat%28int%29) method exposed by [SurfaceHolder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceHolder.html), as returned by [SurfaceView.getHolder()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceView.html#getHolder%28%29)
- the [GLSurfaceView.setEGLConfigChooser()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/GLSurfaceView.html#setEGLConfigChooser%28android.opengl.GLSurfaceView.EGLConfigChooser%29) family of methods

Unless I'm wrong, I think I only need to use the later. Or is using `SurfaceHolder.setFormat()` relevant here?

The documentation of the [EGLConfigChooser](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/GLSurfaceView.EGLConfigChooser.html) class mentions [EGL10.eglChooseConfig()](http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/microedition/khronos/egl/EGL10.html#eglChooseConfig%28javax.microedition.khronos.egl.EGLDisplay,%20int%5B%5D,%20javax.microedition.khronos.egl.EGLConfig%5B%5D,%20int,%20int%5B%5D%29), to discover which configurations are available.

In my case it is ok to fallback to RGB565 if RGB888 isn't available, but I would prefer this to be quite rare.

So, is it possible to use RGB888 on most devices?

Are there any compatibility problems or weird bugs with this?

Do you have an example of a correct and reliable way to setup the GLSurfaceView for rendering RGB888?

Comment: You can always render to RGBA888 FBO and then blit the result to screen.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I assume that by "blit" you imply copying the framebuffer to a Bitmap using the jnigraphics lib, and refreshing a View. Isn't there going to be a huge performance/fps penalty?

Comment: No, by blit I mean `glBlitFramebuffer` onto the FBO containing the viewed GL renderbuffer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

On newer devices, most of them should support RGBA8888 as a native format. One way to force RGBA color format is to set the translucency of the surface, you'd still want to pick the EGLConfig to best guess the config for the channels in addition to the depth and stencil buffers.

```
setEGLConfigChooser(8, 8, 8, 8, 0, 0);
getHolder().setFormat(PixelFormat.RGBA_8888);
```

However, if I read your question correctly you're asking for RGB888 support (alpha don't care) in other words, RGBX8888 which might not be supported by all devices (driver vendor limitation).

Something to keep in mind about performance though, since RGBA8888 is the color format natively supported by most GPUs hardware it's best to avoid any other color format (non natively supported) since that usually translate into a color conversion underneath adding non necessary work load to the GPU.

Comment: Thank you. That's a great answer. That said, if RGBA8888 is usually the native format, how comes GLSurfaceView defaults to RGB565?

Comment: Less bandwith of course, since RGB565 has only 16 bits as opposed to 32bits for RGBA8888. However, note that RGB565 is also widely supported natively by GPUs (it just you wouldn't be able to do alpha blending since there's no alpha). I was just trying to point out the difference between RGBX8888 and RGBA8888 color formats.

Comment: For the record, also for @olivierg, I'd like to mention that _alpha blending_, which is the process of simulating transparency of objects within OpenGL, is independent of the availability of an alpha channel for the Surface you draw on. You won't even notice any difference unless you don't render a fully opaque scene; in other words, you will only notice the absence of a surface alpha channel if you render transparent or translucent scenes which are supposed to show parts of your desktop.

Answer (score -1):

This is how I do it;

```
{
window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

// cocos2d will inherit these values
[window setUserInteractionEnabled:YES]; 
[window setMultipleTouchEnabled:NO];

// must be called before any othe call to the director
[Director useFastDirector];
[[Director sharedDirector] setDisplayFPS:YES];

// create an openGL view inside a window
[[Director sharedDirector] attachInView:window];

// Default texture format for PNG/BMP/TIFF/JPEG/GIF images
// It can be RGBA8888, RGBA4444, RGB5_A1, RGB565
// You can change anytime.
[Texture2D setDefaultAlphaPixelFormat:kTexture2DPixelFormat_];  

glClearColor(0.7f,0.7f,0.6f,1.0f);
//glClearColor(1.0f,1.0f,1.0f,1.0f);

[window makeKeyAndVisible];

[[Director sharedDirector] runWithScene:[GameLayer node]];
```

}

I hope that helps!